# How to fix this on Matlab Index in position 2 exceeds array bounds?

Tags: matlab

I have this following code on my Matlab, now i am getting an  index in position 2 exceeds array bounds. How can i improve it?

```
data = thingSpeakRead(929272, "NumMinutes", 100);
aveTemp = mean(data(:,2)); // This line is the one, i got two fields from my thingspeak channel
apiKey = 'O6P4N8AVZWKNGK5U';
alertURL = "https://api.thingspeak.com/alerts/send";
options = weboptions("HeaderFields",["ThingSpeak-Alerts-API-Key", apiKey]);
alertBody = sprintf("The temperature is %0.2fF.", aveTemp);
alertSubject = sprintf("! Temperature exceeded 60.0F!");

if avg_temperature > 60.0
    webwrite(alertURL, "body", alertBody, "subject", alertSubject, options);
end
```

Comment: What is the size of data?

Comment: size of a data its CSV on my channel on thingspeak, its big. Must that value also need to change? My understanding i thoughts it reference field name on my channel on thingspeak. https://www.mathworks.com/help/thingspeak/sendalert.html

Comment: exceeds array bounds means that the index number is more than the array elements.I don't have ThingSpeak Toolbox in my laptop. Maybe you are reading it wrong.
Try:
data = thingSpeakRead(929272, "NumMinutes", 100);
s=size(data)
and let me know the value of s

Comment: Must the value equates with my fields on my channel? I only got 2 fields on that channel.

Comment: i think yes. Try: data = thingSpeakRead(929272, "NumMinutes", 100); s=size(data)

Comment: I made those changes by changing it to the current function, now i am monitoring to see i wont get any error when its met.

Comment: what line are you getting the error on, and can you output the dimensions of thingspeak?

Comment: Just an advice: It's not a good idea to share your api-key with everyone.

Comment: The dimension of data and the exact error stacktrace should be included in the question.